# Duplicate text in suggestions pop-up

Tags: bug

I've just asked a question and tagged it under `translation`. When I did so, I was shown a pop-up with a duplicate text:

[image: duplicate text]

I'm using Chrome and Windows 10.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced on my local pc. You may elaborate how did you get that?

Comment: @AdInfinitum I just tagged the question with translations, I think then I clicked again where you enter the body of the question and then in the tag section again.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried and the info text, which I got, is not duplicate (not like your screenshot)

Comment: Ok. I have tested it with Mozilla Firefox. Anybody, who uses chrome can also test it like you described it. You may add your first comment to your question because everybody does not read the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that this happened with [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/37398/2594) (I could reproduce it).

The reason for this is that [translation](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) and [english-to-german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-to-german) both trigger the same tag warning (see [this meta post](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1106/2594)). So technically you have been seeing two tag warnings for two different tags, which just happen to be identical.

Unfortunately, from our point of view there is no way to prevent this without losing tag warnings for at least one tag. However these, since new users often tend to use only one of those tags (if any), it is useful to have tag warnings for both tags.