# Wann soll ich welchen Schließgrund bei Fragen nach Übersetzungen, Bedeutungen u. Ä. verwenden?

Tags: support, faq, on-topic, close-reasons

#### Deutsch

Auf Meta gibt es einige Diskussionen darüber, wann Fragen nach Übersetzungen, Bedeutungen, Unterschieden o. Ä. auf dieser Seite willkommen sind und wann sie geschlossen werden sollen. Was ist eigentlich der aktuelle Stand?

*Ich stelle diese Frage, da ich immer wieder beobachte, dass Fragen mit Verweis auf Regeln geschlossen werden, die niemals existierten, oder dass Fragen zwar grenzwertig sind, aber ein Schließgrund gewählt wurde, der dem Fragesteller nicht hilft. Im Gegensatz zu den bisherigen FAQs richtet sich diese an die Nutzer mit Schließrecht und nicht an die Fragesteller.*

*Diese Frage dient nicht dazu, die aktuellen Regeln zu diskutieren, sondern dazu, die Ergebnisse bisheriger Diskussionen widerzuspiegeln. Falls Ihr denkt, dass die Antworten dies nicht tun, kritisiert sie entsprechend. Falls Ihr jedoch mit den hier wiedergegebenen Regeln nicht einverstanden seid, fangt bitte eine neue, getrennte Diskussion an.*

---

#### English

There are some discussions on Meta about which questions asking for translations, meaning, differences and similar are on-topic and which should be closed. What is our current policy?

*I am asking this question because I have observed that sometimes questions are closed with reference to rules that never existed or that questions whose closure might actually be debated are closed with the “wrong” reason, leaving a message that is not really helpful to the asker. In contrast to the existing FAQs, this one is for close voters.*

*Please note that the purpose of this question is to summarise our current policy and not to change it. If you think that the answers do not adequately reflect past discussions, criticise them accordingly. If, however, you disagree with the described policies, please start a new, separate discussion.*

Comment: Hast Du Beispiele für Regeln, die niemals existierten, und Fragen, die deswegen geschlossen wurden?

Comment: @userunknown: Ich sehe regelmäßig Sätze wie »translation questions are off-topic« oder »translation questions to English are off-topic« (was in dieser Allgemeinheit beides nicht stimmt), zwar nicht in Schließgründen (da werden dann die vorgefertigten genommen), aber in »Willkommenskommentaren«. Konkrete Beispiele habe ich gerade nicht zur Hand, da diese Kommentare meist gelöscht sind und die Suche danach unmöglich ist.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Deutsch

### Schaubild

[image]

### Sortiert nach Schließgründen

#### Duplicate

Fragen, deren Duplikat in der jeweils anderen Sprache ist, sollten [in der Regel nicht geschlossen werden](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/807/2594). Ansonsten sind die allgemeinen Stack-Exchange-Regeln anzuwenden.

#### General references

Dieser Schließgrund sollte nicht verwendet werden, wenn die Frage erläutert, warum ein Wörterbuch o. Ä. die Frage nicht beantwortete. Aber auch, wenn dies nicht der Fall ist, [brauchen solche Fragen nicht geschlossen zu werden](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/2594). Wir **können** sie aber schließen, wenn wir denken, dass eine einfache Suche in einem geeigneten Wörterbuch die Frage beantwortet. Sowohl für den Fragesteller als auch für andere, die mit für eine Schließung stimmen sollen, wäre ein Link zu solch einem Wörterbuch hilfreich.

#### Proofreading, spell checking or translations of individual texts

Wenn eine Frage sich in mehrere einzelne Übersetzungsprobleme o. Ä. zerlegt werden kann, sollte dieser Schließgrund angewandt werden. Umgekehrt sollte dieser Schließgrund nicht angewandt werden, wenn sich die Frage um ein einzelnes Wort, eine Redensart oder Phrase dreht ([Faustregel](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1093/2594): etwas, bei dem es vorstellbar ist, dass ein Wörterbuch ihm einen eigenen Eintrag widmet).

#### Expertise of a language other than German

Wenn bei einer Frage nach einer Übersetzung [**ins** Deutsche](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/971/2594) nicht klar ist, was die zu übersetzenden Wörter eigentlich bedeuten, sollte dieser Schließgrund angewandt werden.

Bei einer Frage nach einer Übersetzung [**aus** dem Deutschen](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/136/2594) sollte dieser Schließgrund hingegen angewandt werden, wenn der Fragesteller kein Problem mit dem Verständnis der deutschen Wörter hat – es sei denn, deren Bedeutung ist so kompliziert, dass sie nicht einfach in Worte gefasst werden kann.

#### Too broad

Trifft überwiegend auf Fragen nach Übersetzungen oder Bedeutungen längerer Texte zu. In diesem Fall ist der Schließgrund *proofreading, spell checking or translations of individual texts* besser, da er spezifischer ist und dem Fragesteller eher hilft.

#### Unclear what you’re asking

Ist hoffentlich selbsterklärend. Häufig geht eine Klarstellung damit einher, zu erklären, warum ein Wörterbuch die Frage nicht beantworten konnte. In diesem Fall ist der Schließgrund *general references* hilfreicher.

#### Primarily opinion-based

Sollte auf diesen Typ von Fragen praktisch nie zutreffen.

## English

### Diagram

[image]

### By close reason

#### Duplicate

If the duplicate is the respective other language, the question [should usually not be closed](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/807/2594). Besides this, Stack Exchange’s usual rules apply.

#### General references

This close reason should not be used if the asker elaborates why a dictionary or similar failed to provide an answer. If this is not the case, we [need not close for this reason](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/2594), but can do so, if we think that a simple dictionary search answers the question. For both, the OP, and fellow users whose additional votes are needed, a link to such a general reference would be helpful.

#### Proofreading, spell checking or translations of individual texts

This close reason should be applied, if a question can be split into several separate translation requests or similar. With other words: This close reason does not apply if the question is about a single word, phrase, or idiom ([rule of thumb](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1093/2594): something that **could** be featured as an entry in a dictionary).

#### Expertise of a language other than German

If the question asks for a translation [**to** German](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/971/2594), this close reason should be applied, if it is not clear what the words or phrases in the other language mean.

If the question asks for a translation [**from** German](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/136/2594), this close reason should be applied if the asker fully understands the German words – unless their  meaning is so intricate that it’s difficult to describe with other words.

#### Too broad

This mostly applies to translation requests of longer texts or similar. In this case, the close reason *proofreading, spell checking or translations of individual texts* is preferable, as it is more specific and provides better guidance to the asker.

#### Unclear what you’re asking

Often, elaborating why a dictionary or similar did not answer the question also solves this problem. In this case, the close reason *general references* is more helpful to the asker.

#### Primarily opinion-based

This close reason should hardly ever apply to this type of question.

Comment: Im deutschen Diagramm fehlt auch der Ja-Pfeil bei „Sind tiefergehende Deutschkenntnisse nötig …?“ Beispiele wären gut.

Comment: @Crissov: Pfeil ist korrigiert. Beispiele für alles sind viel Arbeit und werden hoffentlich von den spezifischeren Diskussionen abgedeckt. Gibt es irgendwelche speziellen Fälle, für die Du Dir Beispiele wünschst?

Comment: ch würde vorschlagen, diese Information als link ganz am Anfang der Tour einzublenden  und ebenso zu oberst im Help Center! "HOW TO ASK". Oder ist das nur für die Administratoren? –

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli: Diese FAQ ist speziell an erfahrene Mitglieder gerichtet, die das Recht haben, Fragen zu schließen. Ansonsten habe ich habe die veränderbaren Teile der Tour mal etwas ausführlicher gemacht und [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) steht auch alles Wesentliche. Unser Problem ist eher, dass die Leute die Tour überspringen und auch andere Informationen ignorieren.

Comment: klar, darüber bin ich ja als newbie auch gestolpert.